# Instagram on android emulator

Tags: android, networking, emulation, apk, instagram

Hello I have an android emulator on my PC. I downloaded and installed instagram.apk from www.androiddrawer.com. When I am signing up to Instagram it says "An unknown network error has occured". How to solve this problem?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a issue with the internet connection in you emulator.  Can you get online? Does the browser connect? Otherwise it is most likely an issue with the Instagram app itself.